# Why does the image disappear after the animation(CSS)?

Tags: css, css-animations

for some reason are the image gone when the animation is finished? :/

```css
.coin {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: cover;
    animation: CoinflipRoll 6s steps(199);
    animation-delay: .5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/Mvek2Uy.png");
}

@keyframes CoinflipRoll {
    100% {
        background-position-y: -39800px;
    }
}
```

```html
<small>Image is 248x12648</small>
<div class="coin"></div>
```

Comment: how many frames there are in the image?

Comment: 248x12648, I tried to change background-position to 12648 but then will it just roll through all coins & not one by one

Answer (score 1):

Correct your code like below. You don't need a lot of complex value and you need to set the correct value to `steps()`. Your image contains 50 frames not 199

```css
.coin {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  animation: CoinflipRoll 2s steps(50) .5s forwards;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/Mvek2Uy.png");
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

@keyframes CoinflipRoll {
  100% {
    background-position: bottom;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="coin"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The animation is moving the picture out of the frame. Look at the picture - its still there afterwards, just moved through all the "animation frames". So stop it before it is at the end but manipulating the end value